# Stack Overflow Jobs widget showing jobs in different city

Tags: bug, status-planned, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

The Stack Overflow Jobs widget is showing jobs in a different city ([Sydney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sydney)) to the one I'm staying in ([Melbourne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melbourne)). I've checked that my profile information lists that I'm in Melbourne and even that there were listed jobs located in Melbourne.

While I've tagged this as a bug, I don't know for sure whether this is a bug and if it is something that can be reproduced easily, if at all.

Here's a screenshot of the questions screen with the widget and the job locations highlighted:

[image: Incorrect location for jobs]

Comment: There's not a great deal of information here to go on; which URL are you talking about? Is it the matches tab, most recent, relevance? Some screenshots would be useful!

Comment: Hi Dean, I've added an image. I'd assumed it would be understood if I mentioned it was the careers widget.

Comment: @AshwinNair Most of that is based on your IP. It's possible you're using a VPN or your ISP is resolving to Sidney.

Comment: dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134567/careers-adverts-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are often due to a slightly outdated GeoIP database. I looked at what location your IP was resolving to, and it was finding New South Wales as the region with no city information. The "default" lat/lon for New South Wales is in Sydney, so that's why you were seeing primarily Sydney.

I updated it today, and... bad news. Not only does it still not have the correct region, or know what city you're in, but now it thinks you're in Queensland. So... I hope you're looking for jobs in Brisbane :(.

But seriously, I apologize for that undesired behavior. Respecting user location preferences has been in our backlog for a while, but keeps getting bumped for other experiments. The good news is that the experiment backlog is finally almost empty, so there's a good chance we'll get to it as soon as next week.

Meanwhile, I hope the weather is good in Brisbane!

But really, sorry again.

Comment: Thanks @BrettCopeland....that explains a lot. I access SO from a VM located in Brisbane (don't ask why). Wouldn't it be better if SO Careers used the profile location if mentioned? I know I'd be happy about it if this was a feature.