# Jobs matching for specified current location for users behind proxy

Tags: bug, advertising, stack-overflow-jobs

At `Job Preferences` I've specified my current location (*Dublin*)

and checked on the `Always include your current location` checkbox.

But StackOverflow keeps showing me vacations from London where is my employer's proxy is located.

This is very frustrating.

1. I visit site almost every day but don't see positions I potentially could be interested in.
2. The listed positions just eat screen space and are not relevant to me.
3. If I want to look for search for jobs related to my location I click the jobs widget header and it leads me to job search results with predefined filter for London. I have to change location to Dublin manually every time. As a result I use the feature far less frequently.

I've found 2 similar issues reported but they seems to be neglected:

1. [Use location mentioned in profile for job adverts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327975/use-location-mentioned-in-profile-for-job-adverts)
2. [Stack Overflow Jobs widget showing jobs in different city](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327902/stack-overflow-jobs-widget-showing-jobs-in-different-city)

Comment: We're aware of the problem. I even have some code designed to fix it. It's not 100% there yet because we haven't had the bandwidth as a team to do it.

Comment: I understand, just wanted to highlight that the problem is probably bigger and more annoying to users than it seems. Thanks for reply.